# how to display long integers on browser in php?

Tags: php

```
     echo 246810121416182022242628303234363840;
```

such 
        then it shows me value on brower as
               2.4681012141618E+35
         Please suggest me solution

Comment: Where are you getting this number from? You can print it as a string.

Answer (score 4):

wrap it in ""

```
echo "246810121416182022242628303234363840"
```

Comment: echo "246810121416182022242628303234363840";
$no1=246810121416182022242628303234363840-1;
echo "<br>"."$no1";

$no2=246810121416182022242628303234363840+1;
echo "<br>"."$no2";

Comment: same problem for no1...i ma getting 2.4681012141618E+35 for no1

Comment: and oyput as follow :246810121416182028912708947168722944
246810121416182028912708947168722944

Answer (score 2):

Use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). For example:

```
echo number_format(246810121416182022242628303234363840,0,null,'');
```

Also, you can define custom thousands separator.

Comment: $no=246810121416182022242628303234363840;
       echo number_format($no,0,null,'');
        $no1=$no-1;
       echo "<br>";
       echo number_format($no1,0,null,'');

Comment: echo "246810121416182022242628303234363840"; $no1=246810121416182022242628303234363840-1; echo "<br>"."$no1"; $no2=246810121416182022242628303234363840+1; echo "<br>"."$no2"                                                                                                                                            and nw ouput as follow :246810121416182028912708947168722944 246810121416182028912708947168722944

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with very long integers in PHP, you're going to have trouble regardless of what you try to do.

From [PHP's docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead.

When given an int with value 246810121416182022242628303234363840, PHP interprets it as a float with value 2.4681012141618E+35.  Even attempting to use `number_format()` as Timur suggests will result in printing '246810121416182028912708947168722944'.

Given that PHP can't be passing that value as you describe, you must be typing it in your code?  If this is the case, your best bet for accurate echoing is to create a string instead of an int.

Comment: In other words, [Andreas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9630812/364198) is the correct one.  This is just the why...